# delete all bug string between two words

Tags: php, xml, string, formatting, filtering

I've got a script which generates text. I need to be strip all repeated blocks of text. The string is in xml format, so I can use the beginning and ending tags to determine where the strings are. I've been using substr_replace to remove the unnecessary text... However, this only works if I know how many times said text is going to be present in the string. Example :

```
<container>
  <string1>This is the first string.</string>
  <string2>This is the second string.</string>
  <stuff>This is the important stuff.</stuff>
</container>
```

That container might appear once, twice six times, seven times, whatever. The point is, it's necessary to only have it appear once in the string variable. Right now this is what I'm doing.

```
$where_begin = strpos($wsman_output,'<container');
$where_end = strpos($wsman_output,"</container>");
$end_length = strlen("</Envelope>");
$attack = $where_end - $where_begin;
$attack = $attack + $end_length;
$wsman_output = substr_replace($wsman_output,"",$where_begin,$attack);
```

And I do that for each time the container exists.... However, I just found out that it's not always going to be the same.. Which really messes things up.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you clarify the question please. There is no repeated blocks of text in your example. Also, what is meant by "I just found out that it's not always going to be the same"

Comment: So... That block is just an example of what a single block might look like. There could be 15 of those exact same blocks of text within a string, or two, or just one.

And I mean the blocks aren't going to appear in the same quantity every time. So sometimes there might be 5, the next there could be eight. That's what I mean it won't be the same (so I can't just strip it all out with substr_replace like I was doing before.)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to use the method suggested [here](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/php_string_extract.php).

I pulled each block of string I wanted from the variable, then combined them back together in the required order.